# Passing parameters to Controllers via submit and via action

Tags: asp.net-core

I am relatively new to asp.net core.
I have a cshtml view like so:

```
@model myModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


@using(Html.BeginForm("PostIt","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lmc">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lInt">
    <table>
    @foreach (var item in @Model.lmc)
    {   
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.id">
            <td>@item.name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="bySubmit"/>
    <br>
    <a asp-action="byRoute" asp-route-MC="@Model">byRoute</a>
}
```

My Data Model below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MVCPostList.Models
{
    public class myModel
    {
        public int id{get;set;}
        public List<int> lInt{get;set;}
        public List<myClass> lmc{get;set;}
    }

    public class myClass
    {
        public int id{get;set;}
        public string name{get;set;} 
    }
}
```

and my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MVCPostList.Models;

namespace MVCPostList.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            myModel mm = new myModel();

            mm.lmc = new List<myClass>();

            myClass mc = new myClass();
            mc.id=1;
            mc.name="test1";
            mm.lmc.Add(mc);

            mc = new myClass();
            mc.id=2;
            mc.name="test2";
            mm.lmc.Add(mc);

            mc = new myClass();
            mc.id=3;
            mc.name="test3";
            mm.lmc.Add(mc);

            return View(mm);
        }

        

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult bySubmit(myModel mm)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        public IActionResult byRoute(myModel mm)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Upon clicking bySubmit or byRoute, the myModel.lmc is either null or empty array.
The  doesn't seem to help or I really don't understand what it is for and how to use it. :)
Any help is most appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Sorry the PostIt at the BeginForm has been changed to bySubmit...

Comment: to help diagnose this kind of issue, you can try inspecting the HTML page in the browser, verify the generated names of the FORM inputs. Somehow it may be generated unexpectedly and the model will not be bound correctly.

Comment: this `<input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.id">` should generate the corresponding hidden input whose name is like `lmc[0].id`. But I'm pretty sure that it would not be generated to that format, it may be something like `item.id`. So try changing your `foreach` loop to a `for` loop, use the `@Model.lmc` directly without a temp var, e.g: `<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lmc[i].id">`

Comment: Thank you!!, your suggestion worked for the bySubmit but still failed byRoute. Its enough to get me going for now. Thanks again

Comment: your test with `asp-route` has another kind of issue. this `<a asp-action="byRoute" asp-route-MC="@Model">byRoute</a>` does not form a submit button. You should use `<button>` instead. Also the `asp-route-MC` binds the specified data to the `MC` route key. I do not see any `MC` key in your code. Your form method is "post", so your `byRoute` should also have `HttpPostAttribute` applied. I'm not so sure what you want about using `asp-route-` here, I don't think it can help you bind the whole `@Model` instance in some hidden magical way

Comment: if you want to play with `asp-route` you need to learn about attribute routing in ASP.NET Core by using the `RouteAttribute`. The `asp-route-xxx` will bind data to the xxx key which is put in the route pattern. But only simple data can be bound (string, number, ...) that way. Your `myModel` is a complex model, it can just be bound usually (from query string or form data, not from route data by default).

Comment: Thanks Hopeless for the extended explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your `foreach` loop in your view to just a `for` loop, as @Hopeless suggested like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.lmc.Count(); i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lmc[i].id" />
    <td>@Model.lmc[i].name</td>
}
```

In regard to the `<a></a>` element in your form, I would make it a button and then add a `formaction` attribute to both buttons so it knows which action to execute on submit.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lmc" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lInt" />
    <table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.lmc.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lmc[i].id" />
        <td>@Model.lmc[i].name</td>
    }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" formaction="bySubmit" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" formaction="byRoute" />
}
```

Then your controller would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult bySubmit(myModel mm)
{
    // code to execute
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult byRoute(myModel mm)
{
    // code to execute
}
```

The `asp-route-MC="@Model"` is meant for carrying values in the URL for routing. As such, an entire model would not work. The approach I offered above is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks @gabenotgave. It worked on the small project which i produced to investigate this issue. When I applied it to the actual big project, it did not produced the same result. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: @Mustafa Hmm, that’s odd... Is your form and controller exactly the same?

Comment: Structurally yes the same but there are other manipulations that is occurring there. The actual view also has partial views that’s called recursively to complete the page. I am now wondering if that could affect it

Comment: @Mustafa What exactly doesn’t work? Are the controllers not receiving any POST requests after submitting?

Comment: The parameter arrived as null under 1 condition but in another condition arrived as an incomplete object. The List<> within the object is empty (Count==0) while there were rows in the List<> to build the page.. The <button> clicked with the same formaction. The way the page was constructed differs under different conditions

Comment: @Mustafa If your HTML element names are correct and the form is still reaching the controller, then I’d say it’s safe to assume that your partial views is what is causing the problems. Without seeing your code, I couldn’t offer much further help.